# Why don't hardware failures show up at the programming language level?

Tags: programming-languages

I am wondering if anyone can give my a good answer, or at least point me in the direction of a good reference to the following question:
How come I have never heard of a computer breaking in a very fundamental way? How come when I declare x to be a double it stays as a double? How come there is never a short circuit that robs it of some bytes and makes it an integer? Why do we have faith that when we initialize x to 10, there will  never be a power surge that will cause it to become 11, or something similar?

I think I need a better understanding of memory. 
Thanks, and please don't bash me over the head for such a simple/abstract question.

Comment: Testing. Lots and lots of testing. And then some more testing.

Comment: It depends on what hardware you write software for. I forgot the name of a Mars lander that crashed because it used english over metric units for some task. Most software is written for 'virtualized' and protected environments that you can't do anything worse than crash the program.

Comment: There are no "doubles" or "integers" at a hardware level (unless it's a really exotic platform). There are bit vectors only. And of course bits can change their values randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How come I have never heard of a computer breaking in a very fundamental way?

Hardware is *fantastically* complicated and there are a huge number of engineers whose job it is to make sure that the hardware works as intended. Whenever Intel, AMD, etc. release chips, they've extensively tested the design and run all sorts of diagnostics before it leaves the plant. They have an economic incentive to do this: if there's a mistake somewhere, it can be extremely costly. Look at the Intel [FDIV bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug) for an example.

> How come when I declare x to be a double it stays as a double? How come there is never a short circuit that robs it of some bytes and makes it an integer?

Part of this has to do with how the assembly works. Typically, compiled application binaries don't have any type information in them. Instead, they just issue commands like "take the four bytes at position 0x243598F0 and load them into a register." For a variable's type to mutate somehow, a huge amount of application code would have to change. If there was an error that underallocated the space for the variable, it would mess up the stack layout and probably cause a pretty quick program crash, so chances are the result would be "it crashed" rather than "the type got mutated," especially since at a binary level the operations on doubles and integral types are so different.

> Why do we have faith that when we initialize x to 10, there will never be a power surge that will cause it to become 11, or something similar?

There might be! It's extremely rare, though, because the hardware people do such a good job designing everything. One of the nifty things about being a software engineer is that you sit on top of the food chain:

- Software engineers write software that runs in an operating system,
- which was written by systems programmers and talks to the hardware,
- which was designed by electrical engineers and is built out of hardware gates,
- which were fabricated and designed by materials engineers,
- who got their materials due to the efforts of mining engineers,
- etc.

Lots of engineers make a good living at each link in the chain, which is why everything is so well-tested. Errors do occur, and they do take down real computer systems, but it's relatively rare unless you have thousands or millions of computers running.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, the biggest such problem is *cosmic background radiation*. If a gamma ray hits your memory chip, it can randomly flip a memory bit. This does happen even in your computer every now and then. It usually doesn't cause any problem, since it is unlikely that it is the very bit in your Excel input field, for example, and magnetic drives are protected against such accidents. However, it is a problem for long, large calculations. That's what ECC memory is invented for. You can also find more info about this phenomenon here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory

"The actual error rate found was several orders of magnitude higher than previous small-scale or laboratory studies, with 25,000 to 70,000 errors per billion device hours per megabit (about 2.5–7 × 10−11 error/bit·h)(i.e. about 5 single bit errors in 8 Gigabytes of RAM per hour using the top-end error rate), and more than 8% of DIMM memory modules affected by errors per year."

Comment: That was a pretty cool read, thanks!

Comment: On the Atari 2600 Video Computer System (a popular microprocessor-based video game console in the late 1970's and early 1980's), rapidly flipping the power switch would cause "random" memory corruption.  Although this would often cause games to crash hard, if one practiced flipping the switch at the right speed, one could a significant fraction of the time cause the game to behave oddly without crashing (note that many games only used 1-2 levels of stack, and a large portion of the code would be in the main loop, so errant jumps were often "recoverable".

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1, most of us rarely or never work on a large enough system or one where this type of consideration is needed. In large databases or in file systems, they have error detection to notice what you describe present. In physically or data large systems, errors when writing or storing data happen (ex,. packets get lost or corrupted mid-journey, gamma rays hit). Sectors go bad in your hard drive all the time. We have hashing, parity checking, and a host of other methods to notify us when funny issues happen.

Answer 2: Our axioms & models. The models we tend to use, the Imperative or Functional model, doesn't have the 'gamma ray from the sun changed a bit' present as a consideration. Just like how an environmental scientist may abstract away quarks when studying environmental changes, we abstract away hardware.

Edit #X:
This is a great question. I actually heard this recently, by accident. In Physics, their models are wrong. Dead wrong. And they know they are wrong but they use them anyway. When I said this to justify my distain for the subject, the CS technician at my school verbally back-handed me. He basically said what you said, how do we know 'int x=10' isn't 11 randomly later?